# Problems on Python Code using Theano

Tags: python, variables, shapes, theano

I am learning the Python Theano Library. I just encountered a block of code using Theano shown below:

```
import theano
import theano.tensor as T
from collections import OrderedDict
import numpy

params = OrderedDict()  ### params is a python ordered dictionary.
r = numpy.random.rand(10, 5)    ### Generate a random matrix with dimension of 10 * 5.
params['haha'] = (0.01 * r).astype('float32')   ### insert a key 'haha' with its value into the dictionary.

sparams = OrderedDict() ### sparams is another python ordered dictionary.
sparams['haha'] = theano.shared(params['haha'], name='haha')    ### Create Theano Shared Variable from the params.

x = T.matrix('x', dtype='int64') ### x is a theano tensor matrix

n1 = x.shape[0]     ### What does it mean?
n2 = x.shape[1]     ### What does it mean?

h = sparams['haha'][x.flatten()].reshape([n1, n2, 5])   ### What does it mean?
```

My problem is I cannot understand this part of code:

```
n1 = x.shape[0]     ### What does it mean?
n2 = x.shape[1]     ### What does it mean?

h = sparams['haha'][x.flatten()].reshape([n1, n2, 5])   ### What does it mean?
```

Also, I am wondering if there is any way in Python to check the values as well as dimensions of Theano tensor variables. I really appreciate if anyone can help me solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs `shape` returns an lvector representing the shape of x. You can read more about that [here](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/basic.html#shaping-and-shuffling)

In the code block you are referencing `n1` will return the object at index 0 and `n2` will return the object at index 1.

You can read a bit more about lists in python [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_lists.htm).

If you are running this script from the command line, you can use a `print` statement to see what is contained is those variables by adding a line like this:

`n1 = x.shape[0]
print n1`

Comment: Thank you for your great response! Actually,I tried to print tensor variable by the code: `print h`, but it seemed to print something like: `Reshape{3}.0` . So I cannot figure out the value of tensor variable as well as the dimension. Also, I either don't understand the meaning of `h = sparams['haha'][x.flatten()].reshape([n1, n2, 5])`...